# Import C++ project to Qt Creator through command line

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, scons

I'm looking to import a C++ project to Qt Creator through the command line.

I'm currently using Qt Creator with a C++ project on a Linux machine, and have added it through

> File → New file or project → Import Project → Import Existing Project.

I'd like to make this process easier for my peers by adding projects through the command line, but haven't been able to find how to do that. The project is built using `SCons` rather than `makefiles`, which works fine running as a custom process step in Qt Creator.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What is the use-case to do this from command line? Refer to these [command line options](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-cli.html) page for the available options. And, there's none relevant to your situation i.e. to import / configure a project from command line.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I had seen these and you're correct that there's no relevant commands.  I'm looking into writing a Python (or other) script that can take care of the import/setup.  I'm interested in doing this because the custom process step is stored in the project settings, and I'd like to be able to import a new project where I've taken care of setting that in the script and don't have to type the full path to SCons for every new project.

Comment: Right. So, you want to automate this import sequence, right? Using Python, how do you plan to do that? GUI automation?

Comment: Is there some project file which Qt Creator uses? Can you alter that to add files/etc?

Comment: Since I'm using C++ files and not Qt projects, there is no .pro file which is used.  Instead, it generates <project-name>.(config, creator, creator.user, files, and includes).  Because my main concern is having the build settings pre-set (which are strored in <project-name>.creator.user, I've tried creating that file first in my project location by using a copy of it from a correct project, but with workspace path info removed.  Qt Creator sees this file when I import the project, but writes over it with the default build settings.

Comment: Haven't read through it yet, but there appears to be information on using an existing creator.user file [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998046/qt-creator-doesnt-load-settings-from-externally-generated-creator-user-file) that I'm hoping can help. Edit: no help, they did not reach a solution there